# How to select the ID that's before another ID

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to do a CSS selection.
I want to select an ID that's before another ID selector.
This is the example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div class="aside_left">Left content...</div>
     <div class="main_page">Main content...</div>
</div> <!-- end of wrapper -->
```

My objective is that the `main_page` stay on the left, and the `aside_left` change its position to the right.

Both the `aside_left` and the `main_page` have the property `float:left` I can't change the `aside_left` property to `float:right` because it is in many pages.

Is it possible to  select the ID or CLASS that is before another ID?

My selector should be something like this: **select the .aside_left that are before an .main_page**

Comment: Generally this is not possible with pure CSS. However, what is present instead if `.main_page` is missing? (What does the html structure look like if on the other pages where there is no `.main_page`)?

Comment: Also, you mention "ID" but your two div's are not by ID, but by classes in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do this with CSS selectors per se.. your best bet is to use something like jQuery's very accessible `.parent()` [method](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

You can see [here for CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) and [here for CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching), this is not present in the current spec.

The speculative design for [CSS4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) does provide such a selector using a `!` operator, but is not presently supported in any browser.

With this in mind, perhaps think about changing the logic behind what you're trying to do- can you not give the altered elements different class names to more easily identify them? Or progress down from your wrapper element?

Or, have a look into the nth-of-type selector, by using:

`#wrapper .aside_left:nth-of-type(odd)`

See **[THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rY2WK/1/)**

This will select only the .aside_left elements which are the first child of the #wrapper element. The first child, as in the first in the DOM, as opposed to the first displayed (using `float` may visually produce results that dont reflect actual DOM positioning in which case you're back to using jQuery).

Comment: I don't know jQuery and I can't change the HTML code, all I can work with is the CSS stylesheet, that's why I wanted that strange selector.

I already knew the nth-of-type selector, but is not exactly what I was looking for. I want to select only the aside_left if there's a main_page class in the page.

The problem is that there are many combinations; aside_left + contact_page, aside_left + product_page, aside_left + category_page... and I just wanted to select the aside_left of the main_page.

I will ask the webmaster to change the html code flow. Thank's !

Comment: @Gekyzo you're welcome, sorry there isnt a way to do what you're after in CSS

Answer (score 0):

### Only if *HTML Structure* Cooperates is Pure CSS Possible

I noted in my comment and ExtPro has noted in his answer that such is not possible by pure css, ***at least under most conditions***. However, there is ***one set of conditions*** that it is possible. That is if there end up being more child elements of `#wrapper` in the html when something other than `.main_page` is present. This would be a very specifc case requirement, and may not match your situation (probably not based off your comment to ExtPro), but if so, then this code works:

```
#wrapper > .aside_left:nth-last-of-type(2) {
    float: right;
}
```

[See an example fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/49YpD/1/) You see how ***this requires that there be two elements only in the case that the `.main_page` is there***, and would demand more elements be present if `.main_page` is not there. So this technically does not key in on `.main_page` itself, but rather is using the html structure to change a preceding element based off the number of sibling elements present.

Comment: Wow, I didn't saw this posibility. I will try this and see if it crash. Thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 0):

in pure CSS you could use display:flex and order , despite position in the flow of `.main_page` : (hover it to see them both switching sides).

```
 /* using your HTML */
 #wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height:200px;
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
}
#wrapper > div {
  width:20%;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 1px;
  order:2;
}
#wrapper .main_page {
  width:80%;
}
#wrapper > div.aside_left {
background:gray;
}
#wrapper > div.main_page:hover {
  order:1;
}
```

live démo at http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Iywbj see some tips to use it here : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You could as well reset direction on #wrapper  if you style your 2 div as inl'ne-boxes and restore direction on the childs divs